How to integrate external templates to Laravel + Vite?
For reference, I'm using Laravel 11
I have an external templates with their own css and javascripts, by default, laravel 11 comes in with simple vite implementation that uses:
//vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css', 
                'resources/js/app.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

So I will just run build or run dev to generate css and js files and dynamically calling those in blade files using:
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

This assumes I'll do all the designing myself. But I have a template I want to include.
I know I can just declare them manually on blade templates but I wanted to include them to the compiled files.
How do I do this the right way?

Add css and js files under resources/css and resources/js.
For example:
resources/css/new-styles.css
resources/js/new-script.js

You would also need to add them in your vite.config.js
//vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                // defaults
                'resources/css/app.css', 
                'resources/js/app.js'

                // css
                'resources/css/new-styles.css', 

                // js
                'resources/js/new-script.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

Adding the files in vite will make npm run build create files under public/build.
Below is a sample file that will be created:
public/build/assets/css/new-styles-hashcode.css
public/build/assets/js/new-script-hashcode.js

You can insert the files in blade with
@vite(['resources/css/new-styles.css'])
@vite(['resources/js/new-script.js'])

But I would prefer to do
<link href="{{ Vite::asset('resources/css/new-styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/js/new-script.js') }}" ></script>

Both options will hotreload with npm run dev and versioned with npm run build
This is just a guide on how to add your assets in Laravel 11 + vite.
As for your templates, you would need to add them to the corresponding directory.
ex: if in template css are in css/file1/file2/styles.css, then you would also upload your css in resources/css/file1/file2/styles.css the same with js. Then update as needed.

throws a lot of js undefined errors, the js files are not loading in a right manner

Have you added them in the right place? No typo errors? Update your question so that we can check

js undefined errors might be because the JS files you added are also trying to execute methods from npm packages. Make sure that the npm packages from the template you are trying to use is also installed in your laravel app. (if those packages exist and is compatible with your laravel+vite project)

question still the same though. the js/css files from the template are minified and calling them in the html in a conventional way works. when calling them using your example, js errors which I pointed out that the js are not loading in the right manner. example like jquery

I updated how the JS is called. Earlier I made it self closing () instead of (). As for the assets itself, try to remove the minified version and just add plain old js file with console log or alert.

What do you mean conventional way of calling them in HTML? Do you mean calling them as plain script tag?

Yes calling them manually via script tag works, but including them in vite doesnt. Your modification in js closing script works but only in run dev, js errors again in build

Try to compare what the value of {{ Vite::asset('resources/js/new-script.js') }} if it match with the src of your asset in conventional way

Can you update your question? Which part you changed. etc.

Working on dev works meaning the answer is correct. Not working in build means your vite setup may be wrong. Make sure that you update your vite on the correct route for you asset. Also before you build, try to delete the files in public/build then run build to rebuild the assets

I'll accept the answer as it helped me in dev env. the problem is the build env. vite includes the template js files and process it as es modules (which should not)
